# Redirect to particular tab on a page from a different page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 pages and in page 2 we have dynamically tabs created . In page 1 I have a button and when I click that button I open a form and fill the details and select under which tab i have to show this information (Usually we select  tabs in page 2) .

Now once i click on submit button in page 1, I am able to navigate to page 2. But I also want to navigate to tab level. In short I have to navigate to page 2 (which ever tab i selected earlier).  How to do this in angular JS.

For naviagating I am using `window.location("/page2)"`.

My code is

`<div ng-repeat="t in tdata"  class="time-tab-adspace " ng-class="{'tab-align-center':tdata.length==2}">
                        <a class="nav-people-tab text-hover" data-toggle="tab" ng-class="{'nav-people-tab-hover in': 'ticket'+seltab=='ticket'+t.code}"  ng-click="selecttab(t)" data-target="#ticket{{$index}}">{{t.name}}
                        </a>

                    </div>`

A piece of working snippet would be appreciated greatly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide Fiddle/Code

Comment: No. I am using angular js and javascript

Answer (score 1):

Tell the page which tab has to be activated. This can be done via $localStorage if you don't want to add search parameters to the url.

In your function which calls the page2:

```
$localStorage.nextTab = 2;
```

Now in your page2, you can access this tab number and set the tab at the startup.

```
$scope.setTab($localStorage.nextTab);
```

See [ng-storage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

You can use `window.localStorage` if you need to do it in plain JS

Comment: i got the values of my selected tab and i am also posting the information to that selected tab correctly . Only problem is it is not navigating to that tab on page load of page 2. Can any one please help me . I am using local storage also to get the required values. Only redirecting problem .. Please provide some code for me to understand. I am new to angular

Comment: Is there any function like window.location.something("param1", "param2") so if i send them it directly navigates to that?

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you further unless you show your code.

Comment: hi charlie. I have tried exactly what you have said. but still I am not able to navigate to selected tab. I cross verified with the tab and it is the right tab only

Comment: As I said, how would I ever imagine what the problem is without knowing how you try to select the tab?

Comment: Hi charlie. I have posted the code that i am using for selecting the tab and ng-class applied to highlight the tab .Hope at least this gives a little idea. Looking forward to your comments

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is to set the selected tab as query string parameter. So you will have for navigation:

```
window.location("/page2?tab=2)"
```

And in the controller check for the query string `tab` value and activate the corresponding tab.

Comment: my url to the page is /page2 only. It shouldn't change. I only have to navigate to the tab . That's it

Comment: This won't change the URL. You are passing additional parameter. /page2?tab=2 will take you to page2 only. Can you give a try?

Comment: Which angular router are you using?

Comment: I am not using any routers. My code is if($scope.result==1)  { window.location.replace("/page2");  }

Comment: can you try window.location.replace("/page2?tab=2") and see if it is taking to same page and you if you are able to get the value of tab?